# How to read read json data from mysql thrugh pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation

I have this type of json in mysql db column which i want to read using python and convert in CSV.

```
{"type":["11","27","26","6"],
 "comment":["","","","ADVANCE"],
 "remark":["","","","anything"],
 "unit":["1.00","1.00","1.00","5000"],
 "rate":["1300000","1409.37","100","1"],
 "extra":["1.00","850","850","1"],
 "amount":["1300000.00","1197964.50","85000.00","5000.00"]}
```

I need final output like this:

```
"type","comment","remark","unit","rate","extra","amount"
"11","","","1.00","1300000","1.00","1300000.00"
"27","","","1.00","1409.37","850","1197964.50"
"26","","","1.00","100","850","85000.00"
"6","ADVANCE","anything","5000","1","1","5000.00"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This will be `import csv` and then `pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('test.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, index=False)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so by using pandas and json modules we maybe have a solution. This is the code from your raw data to csv file :

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = {"type":["11","27","26","6"],
 "comment":["","","","ADVANCE"],
 "remark":["","","","anything"],
 "unit":["1.00","1.00","1.00","5000"],
 "rate":["1300000","1409.37","100","1"],
 "extra":["1.00","850","850","1"],
 "amount":["1300000.00","1197964.50","85000.00","5000.00"]}

json_object = json.dumps(data, indent=1)
results = pd.read_json(json_object)

results.to_csv(path_or_buf = 'location\\data_json.csv', index = False, encoding = 'UTF-8', sep = ',')
```

Output :

```
type,comment,remark,unit,rate,extra,amount
11,,,1,1300000.0,1,1300000.0
27,,,1,1409.37,850,1197964.5
26,,,1,100.0,850,85000.0
6,ADVANCE,anything,5000,1.0,1,5000.0
```

Hope it help you. If is not what you wanted, please give more informations or context. Great day.